# Can't connect to Tomcat via Apache HTTP Server using mod_jk

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat

Issue: I can't connect to my Apache Tomcat site through the Apache HTTP Server using the mod_jk. I can access the Tomcat website when I define the URL with the port number, example: http://localhost:8080/tomcat-demo/helloworld, but when I do http://localhost/tomcat-demo/helloworld it is unable to find the site returning the response:
"*404 Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8080"*

**Software**
Ubuntu Desktop
Tomcat 9
Apache HTTP Server 2.4

**I have followed these guides:**
https://medium.com/@nariyapratik84/installing-tomcat-9and-apache2-with-mod-jk-on-ubuntu-updated-ddc4e8f5d794
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/connecting-apache-web-server-tomcat-and-writing-re-direct-rules
https://www.xmodulo.com/configure-tomcat-cluster-ubuntu.html

**All steps:**

1. Re-install apache2 and tomcat9

```
apt-get remove apache2 && apt-get remove tomcat9
apt-get purge apache2 && apt-get purge tomcat9
apt-get update && apt-get install apache2 && apt-get install tomcat9
```

2. Allow port 8080 in firewall

```
ufw allow "Apache Full" && ufw allow 8080 && ufw enable
```

3. Create a test application for Tomcat

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps
sudo mkdir tomcat-demo
sudo mkdir tomcat-demo/helloworld
sudo nano tomcat-demo/helloworld/index.jsp
```

4. Paste below content to index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
Today is: <%= new java.util.Date().toString() %>
</body>
</html>
```

I can now reach http://localhost:8080/tomcat-demo/helloworld

5. Install the mod_jk and enable the tomcat connector

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk
nano /etc/tomcat9/server.xml <-- Uncomment:
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

6. Configure mod_jk

```
nano /etc/apache2/workers.properties <-- Add the following code inside:
   
# Define 1 real worker using ajp13
worker.list=worker1
# Set properties for worker (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009

nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf <-- Add:
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
```

7. Configure Apache HTTP Server VirtualHost

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf <-- Add below:
<VirtualHost *:8080>    
   JkMount /api worker1 
</VirtualHost>
```

8. Restart Apache and Tomcat

```
service tomcat9 restart && service apache2 restart
```

Even after restart I can't reach http://localhost/tomcat-demo/helloworld. All other settings in Apache2 and Tomcat9 are default (as I re-installed and purged them). $JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Not overly familiar with mod_jk, but `redirectPort="8443"` looks possibly incorrect if you're running on port `8080`.

Comment: I have also been running on 8000 and 80. Still same result unfortunately.